# Java code for a 10 times table

Tags: java

I have this code, it makes a times table, but what I need it to do is just a 10 times table, meaning 10 x 1 is 10, 10 x 2 is 20, 10 x 3 is 30........etc up to 10 x 10 is 100, this is the code that I have, but I can't figure out how to edit it to this. Can anyone help me?

```
public class TimesTable {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int lowerValue = 1;
    int upperValue = 10;

    for (int headingIndex = lowerValue; headingIndex <= upperValue; headingIndex++) {
      System.out.print("\t" + headingIndex);
    }
    System.out.print('\n');

    for (int inner = lowerValue; inner <= upperValue; inner++) {
      System.out.print(inner);
      for (int outer = lowerValue; outer <= upperValue; outer++) {
        System.out.print("\t"+(inner*outer));
      }
      System.out.print('\n');
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it does not need a double loop for printing the inner output

```
    int lowerValue = 1;
    int upperValue = 10;

    for (int headingIndex = lowerValue; headingIndex <= upperValue; 
             headingIndex++) {
      System.out.print("\t" + headingIndex);
    }
    System.out.print('\n');

    int inner = 10;
    System.out.print(inner);
      for (int outer = lowerValue; outer <= upperValue; outer++) {
        System.out.print("\t"+(inner*outer));
      }
      System.out.print('\n');
```

output

```
      1     2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
10    10    20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this meet your need

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int lowerValueHorizontal = 1;
    int lowerValue = 10;
    int upperValue = 10;

    for (int headingIndex = lowerValueHorizontal; headingIndex <= upperValue; headingIndex++) {
        System.out.print("\t" + headingIndex);
    }
    System.out.print('\n');

    for (int inner = lowerValue; inner <= upperValue; inner++) {
        System.out.print(inner);
        for (int outer = lowerValueHorizontal; outer <= upperValue; outer++) {
            System.out.print("\t"+(inner*outer));
        }
        System.out.print('\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to take the second for loop out

```
public class TimesTable {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int lowerValue = 1;
int upperValue = 10;

for (int headingIndex = lowerValue; headingIndex <= upperValue; headingIndex++) {
  System.out.print("\t" + headingIndex);
}
System.out.print('\n');

//for (int inner = lowerValue; inner <= upperValue; inner++) {
  int inner = 10;
  System.out.print(inner);
  for (int outer = lowerValue; outer <= upperValue; outer++) {
    System.out.print("\t"+(inner*outer));
  }
  System.out.print('\n');
//}
}

}
```

School project ? :)

Answer (score -1):

Well, we want to keep the heading, which prints from 1 to 10. What we want to change is the row to only use 10. So rather than having a 10 x 10 table, we will have a 1 x 10 table.

```
public class TimesTable {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int lowerValue = 1;
    int upperValue = 10;

    for (int headingIndex = lowerValue; headingIndex <= upperValue; headingIndex++) {
      System.out.print("\t" + headingIndex);
    }
    System.out.print('\n');

    for (int inner = lowerValue; inner <= upperValue; inner++) {
      System.out.print(inner);
      // Set outer to 10.
      for (int outer = 10; outer <= upperValue; outer++) {
        System.out.print("\t"+(inner*outer));
      }
      System.out.print('\n');
    }
  }

}
```

So changing outer to 10, you'll only use 10 for the inner loop. Hence, while the outer loop goes from 1 to 10, the inner loop stays at 10.

1 x 10, 2 x 10, etc.

Comment: this is redundant `for (int outer = 10; outer <= upperValue; outer++) {`

Comment: @linstantnoodles see my comment

Comment: It's to demonstrate the concept. How the OP decides to optimizes is up to him/her. Sure, you can suggest that we simply make 10 a variable. Or maybe even get rid of the loop all-together. But, not what the question is asking for.